# Обработка во views

Tags: python, django, views

```py
def choice(request, test_id):
    test = get_object_or_404(Test, id=test_id)
    questions = Question.objects.all().filter(test=test)
    question = questions.order_by("id")[0]
    answers = Answer.objects.all().filter(question=question)
    form = AnswerForm(question=question)
    if request.method == "POST":
        value = request.POST
        answer = value.get("answer")
        answerss = get_object_or_404(Answer, id=answer)
        if answerss.truth == True:
            Answer.votes_true = +1
    context = {"test": test, "question": question, "answer": answers, "form": form}
    return render(request, "assay/test.html", context)
```

В строке `question = questions.order_by("id")[0]` я выбираю первый вопрос, заданного теста. На страницу выводится данный вопрос и форма с вариантами ответов.  Как мне после POST запроса, перейти ко второму вопросу и т.д до конца всех вопросов?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно изменить значение переменной question, чтобы она содержала следующий вопрос

```
def choice(request, test_id):
    test = get_object_or_404(Test, id=test_id)
    questions = Question.objects.all().filter(test=test)
    question_index = 0
    question = questions[question_index]
    answers = Answer.objects.all().filter(question=question)
    form = AnswerForm(question=question)
    if request.method == "POST":
        value = request.POST
        answer = value.get("answer")
        answerss = get_object_or_404(Answer, id=answer)
        if answerss.truth == True:
            Answer.votes_true = +1
        question_index += 1
        if question_index < len(questions):
            question = questions[question_index]
            answers = Answer.objects.all().filter(question=question)
            form = AnswerForm(question=question)
    context = {"test": test, "question": question, "answer": answers, "form": form}
    return render(request, "assay/test.html", context)
```

Comment: в строке question_index = 0, индекс становиться опять равным ноль. Дальше первого индекса уйти не получается.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, Aleksandr Fetisov. Идея рабочая, слегка переделал:

```
question_index = 0

def choice(request, test_id):
  test = get_object_or_404(Test, id=test_id)
  questions = Question.objects.all().filter(test=test)
  global question_index
  question = questions[question_index]
  answers = Answer.objects.all().filter(question=question)
  form = AnswerForm(question=question)
  if request.method == "POST":
      value = request.POST
      answer = value.get("answer")
      answerss = get_object_or_404(Answer, id=answer)
      question_index += 1
      if answerss.truth == True:
         Answer.votes_true = +1
      if question_index < len(questions):
         question = questions[question_index]
         answers = Answer.objects.all().filter(question=question)
         form = AnswerForm(question=question)
      if question_index == len(questions):
         rezult = Answer.votes_true / len(questions) * 100
         print(rezult)
```